# How do you create indoor navigation with a line to follow?

Tags: ios, algorithm, navigation, beacon

I created an app on swift that gives step by step direction to navigate through a building. I did the coding manually by creating directions for each location. I know there is an easier way of doing this but I don't know how. How would I get a line that shows the path? Do you need beacons?

Answer (score 0):

Beacons are a small piece of a solution:  beacon signals can provide you a set of inputs to estimate the X/Y coordinates of a receiving phone within a building.  But going from beacons to an X/Y coordinate requires a much larger system and a whole lot of code.  This is certainly not something for a beginner to tackle.

Next, you need a digital map, and a way of rendering it on the screen.   You can use a SVG image and scale it to fit, or you can use SDKs like Google Maps and use overlays.

After that, you need to build a data structure containing a set of paths in the map coordinate scheme, which shows the different ways you can possibly walk, and the intersecting points where you can change from one path to another.  Once you have this, you need an algorithm to find the shortest path from the origin to the destination using a subset of these paths.

Finally, you need to plot on the chosen paths on the map to show how to get from the origin to the destination.

If this all sounds pretty complex, that's because it is.  The details of how to do each step are in and of themselves too complex to answer on StackOverflow.com.

Comment: This actual clears some things up for me the way you explain it. If I would like to dive deeper into this area what do you recommend I learn from. Also, do you think a semi-beginner can tackle something like this without using beacons and just a digital map?

Comment: Beacons aren't generally good at user location in indoor spaces. You need a great many of them and even then when you try to triangulate based on their supposed distance/accuracy, reflections against hard surfaces usually screw it up.  There are better technologies.  If you'd like to discuss how to do all of what was mentioned above (3D indoor mapping, indoor positioning, routing), I have exactly what you need to do all of it. You can reach me as smartcat on the [iOS Developers](https://ios-developers.io/) slack.

Comment: I should clarify that beacons ARE good at user location in indoor spaces if all you're wanting to do is know when a user is at a designated location close to a beacon (an entrance, a product display, etc..)